# Dynamic number of request parameters for web performance testing in Visual Studio

Tags: performance, load-testing, visualstudio

I need to change several requests parameters list to make it dynamic. The number of parameters can differ and depends on previous request responses.

In JMeter it can be done just using the regular expression extractor result parameter which contains array of values.

How can i perform this in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the RegularExpression Extraction rule does not work for you, then what you're looking for is a custom extraction rule: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243179%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Basically create a method deriving from ExtractionRule and then add the ExtractionRule to your webtest.